# Se puede renombrar archivos para cada sesion?

Tags: php, svg

Tengo en una web, imagenes nombradas por ejemplo: "imagen01.png", "imagen02.png", "imagen03.jpg" a las cuales por un tema de optimización, necesito llevarlas si o si a SVG. Anduve leyendo sobre lo vulnerable que son éstos archivos ante un ataque XSS y me quedé preocupado. Entonces pensé en usar esos mismos archivos SVG sin renombrar, y que al momento de la carga de la página sea "renombrado" aleatoriamente de modo que el usuario nunca pueda ver el nombre real, por ejemplo "Shg9mOA.svg" y que ésto vaya cambiando en cada sesión. No necesito código, sólo leer opiniones acerca si estoy encarando bien el problema... ¿Traerá sobrecarga al servidor? ¿Se puede hacer con PHP? ¿Con qué función? ¿Hay una solución alternativa más fácil/simple?

Comment: Hola Max Powel, bienvenido a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Comment: Todo depende de como muestres tus `svg`s. Aparte si no son generados por el usuario no creo que exista mayor problema, a menos que tu les inyectes código malicioso :O

Comment: @KacosPro Muchas gracias! Lo leeré y tendré en cuenta!

Comment: @KacosPro tenés razón! Con permisos 755 bastaría ya que son subidas propias! Mala cabeza la mia! Me perseguí tanto en la complejidad de la seguridad que me olvidé de lo simple :)